# How to place file pointer one line up before writing in file using python?

Tags: python, file, file-pointer

> Scenario

There is a file which contains two blank lines at the end. When I append something to the file, it gets written after two blank lines (which is certain).

But I want only one blank line and remove the second blank line. In place of second blank line, the appending data should be written.

```
#-------Original file 
This is line 1 
This is line 2
[--blank line--] 
This is line 3
This is line 4
[--blank line--]
[--blank line--]
```

Appending "This is line 5" and "This is line 6" in above file.

> What is happening right now!

```
#-------Original file 
This is line 1 
This is line 2
[--blank line--] 
This is line 3
This is line 4
[--blank line--] 
[--blank line--]  
This is line 5
This is line 6
```

> What I want !

```
#-------Original file 
This is line 1 
This is line 2
[--blank line--] 
This is line 3
This is line 4
[--blank line--]  #Only one blank line. Second blank line should be removed
This is line 5
This is line 6
```

I have researched and came to the solution to moving file pointer. While appending contents into file, the file pointer may be present after the second blank line. 
Will it work if I move the file pointer one line up and then append "This is line 5" and "This is line 6" ?

If yes, then please assist on how should I do that. 
Seek() function not seems so useful !

Any idea other than seek() is also appreciated.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please show your code. If you are already reading the file line by line, you can cache the FP position before each read.

Comment: There's no code yet but it would be a simple file open with append mode and then writing those two lines in it. 
Can you please tell me something about moving the file pointer one line up. 
The idea is clear in my mind. I just wanna know how to move the shift file pointer one line up. 
Once it is done, pointer will be at start of second blank line and as I will append something, the blank line would be gone and "This is line 5" will be appended there.

Comment: @otus : simple seek(0) function shifts the pointer to the start of the file. Is there anything I can do that only shifts file pointer one line above ?

Comment: The usual approach to modifying text files is rewriting each entire file.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple way that reads through the file line by line, then restores the pointer to what it was after the second-last:

```
with open('fname', 'rw') as f:
    prev = pos = 0
    while f.readline():
        prev, pos = pos, f.tell()
    f.seek(prev)
    # Use f
```

If you don't want to spend time reading through the file, you will need to decide e.g. what line-endings to support, while here Python will do that for you.

Comment: This does not work because `for line in f` uses a read-ahead buffer.

Comment: @JanneKarila: Oops, accidentally worked in my test by dumb luck. Fixed.

Comment: I am going to have a look at this. Thanks @otus. I appreciate the help.

Comment: @otus - hey I solved it with some modification. Thank you so much. You got me the idea. I will post my answer :)

Answer (score 2):

[This is solution according to appropriate scenario and works only for '\n' case]

Let me thank @otus. His answer + some modification solved my query. :)

According to the scenario, where I wanted to start appending new lines, the file pointer was at the end, by default.

```
#-------Original file 
This is line 1 
This is line 2
[--blank line--] 
This is line 3
This is line 4
[--blank line--]
[--blank line--]
* <-----------------------file pointer is here.
```

Say file1 is the file object.
I used file1.tell() to get the current position of file pointer.

Before writing into file I just did this :

```
 pos = file1.tell() #gives me current pointer
 pos =  pos - 1     #This will give above value, where second blank line resides
 file1.seek(pos)    #This will shift pointer to that place (one line up)
```

And now I can usually continue with writing like file1.write("This is line 5") and so on...

Thanks otus and Janne(especially for buffer issue)..

Comment: Like I alluded in my answer, your solution will only work with EOL markers of length 1, i.e. `'\n'`. Windows' `'\r\n'` will get corrupted.

Comment: I think this goes back one character, not one line. I imagine your file uses one character to terminate lines, and your last line happens to be blank, but this is not a good solution in general.

Comment: Yeah, what otus said.

Comment: Andrew - You are absolutely correct. In my case, I have two blank lines. So if I do pos = pos - 1, it directly takes me to above line.

Comment: otus - yes you are correct. But I have designed the code according to scenario and its fulfilling the needs for now. cheers :)
That one extra blank line is getting created unnecessarily (I don't know why) and I have checked this code with that. Its working fine.

Comment: Andrew : my files are not getting terminated by one character as you mentioned above. Actually I am running commands through python script and writing the output to file. But one extra blank line is getting written to the file which is basically ('\n'). Don't worry, I will not use the above idea in file operations. :)

Comment: @v1h5, your answer will be left here for those who arrive later with a similar problem (e.g. through Google). For them `seek(tell()-1)` is a potential bug.